# Find last matching value in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, find

I have dataframe with column "status" with values:
True,
False,
False,
True,
True

I would like to find the last position of False and get dataframe with only last two values.

Comment: hi Teresa! did you mean for that second False to False, not 'Flase'?

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

# dataframe as you described
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'status' : [True, False, False, True, True]
})

# get the row number of the last False (credit to mozway for index idea)
last_false = df.index[~df['status']].max()

# get every row after the last false
df.loc[last_false+1:]

# or just getting the last two rows
df.tail(2)
```

Comment: @mozway I wasn't sure if you wanted to be associated with my lacklustre python code :p ..but I did get that idea from your comment a few days ago, so it felt right to credit you

Answer (score 2):

One option with [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) and [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) to avoid relying on the range index:

```
df.iloc[df.loc[::-1, 'status'].shift(-1).eq(False).idxmax():]
```

Output:

```
   status
3    True
4    True
```

Answer (score 1):

With `Series.mask` + `Series.last_valid_index`:

```
df.iloc[df['status'].mask(df['status']).last_valid_index() + 1:]
```

---

```
   status
3    True
4    True
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `index`

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "status": [True, False, False, True, True]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
val = df[df['status'] == False].index[-1]
df_final = df.iloc[val+1:,:]
print(df_final)

status
3    True
4    True
```